# use distinct with multiple columns in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

my table structure is as below

```
date        seller  unit    price   total
05-06-17    abc     14      700     9800
05-06-17    pqr     12      600     7200
05-06-17    abc     10      520     5200
06-06-17    abc     10      600     6000
06-06-17    pqr     15      520     7800
06-06-17    pqr     16      520     8320
```

I need to fetch record like

```
1) 'date' = '05-06-2017', 'seller' = 'abc', 'total' = '15000'
2) 'date' = '05-06-2017', 'seller' = 'pqr', 'total' = '7200'
3) 'date' = '06-06-2017', 'seller' = 'abc', 'total' = '6000'
4) 'date' = '06-06-2017', 'seller' = 'pqr', 'total' = '16120'
```

I need data from database in date wise. `seller` `abc` has two entry in a table for `date` `05-06-2017` so I need `total` of that day for `seller` `abc` as well `pqr` same things for the second `date` for all `seller`

Comment: Please describe your required data in detail. Last line is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever we have multiple rows with same data that needs to be merged together in final output, we use **group by** functionality of **mySQL**.

so in your case you can use laravel query builder to do it in this way.

```
 DB::table('orders')->select('date', 'seller', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'))
    ->groupBy('seller')
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get();
```

**Explanation**

`DB::table('orders')->select('date', 'seller', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'))`
will query our `orders` table in our database & then fetch our provided columns i.e. `date, seller and sum of total column as total`

`->groupBy('seller')->groupBy('date')` It will merge the multiple records of same seller in same date.

`->get();` we are get getting our data from the query.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->select('date', 'seller', DB::raw('SUM(total)'))
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->groupBy('seller')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use distinct with multiple columns like this(checked it in Laravel 8).

```
Product::where('column_name','=', $searchTerm)
->distinct('column1','column2')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $request->search;

    $productSearch = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->get();

       return $produtcSearch;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.