# How to get distinct value for column with other column value in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table `activites` in that table it have columns `id, name, description, type, user_id, created_at, updated_at` from that i want to group by `user_id and type` and `created_at` want to be unique. How can i do it in laravel?

For this i did little bit of search but i didn't find any solution for this.
To get unique column value some places mentioned like

`$q = DB::table('activities')->distinct()->get(['created_at']);`

here my question is how to get other column value?

without unique filter my current query look like

```
$q = DB::table('activities')
    ->select(DB::raw('user_id, type, count(*) as total'))
    ->whereNotNull('user_id');
    ->groupBy('user_id', 'type')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think you need to use two different groupBy to achieve the result you want.

Comment: can you please give me how can i achieve this with two different `groupBy`.Thanks

Comment: Took a quick read through, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382353/use-distinct-with-multiple-columns-in-laravel and not confident enough to post it as an answer, just trying to be helpful.